# Bootstrap- Inline forms not aligning properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following code for my inline form (bootstrap 3) but that doesn't seem to work with Google Chrome. I tried it with Firefox and it worked great. Screenshots:

**Chrome**

http://oi58.tinypic.com/148jjw5.jpg

**Firefox**

http://oi58.tinypic.com/5fiy41.jpg

The HTML and CSS I'm using:

```
<style>
.form-inline .form-group {
    margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 4px;
}
.form-inline > .form-group {
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
<form id="callForm" action="sendCall.php"  method="post"  class="form-inline" >

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="your">Your phone number</label>
<span class="input-group-addon">+91</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your" name="your" placeholder="Your 10 digit number" required />
</div>
</div>


 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
 <div class="input-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="frnd">Friend's number</label>
<span class="input-group-addon">+</span>
    <input text="text" class="form-control" id="frnd" name="frnd" placeholder="Your friend's number" required />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Connet</button>
</div>
</form>
<script>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838805/bootstrap-3-inline-forms-are-not-aligning-properly-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any issue with the code that you pasted. You are probably running out of the space inside the container. Try increasing the size of container or reducing the size of form controls.

This is the jsfiddle on chrome, expand the results area: http://jsfiddle.net/w1o26gn0/

Comment: Thx for the answer, have you made any changes in your jsfiddle code?