# Bootstrap 3- Inline forms are not aligning properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following code for my inline form (bootstrap 3) but that doesn't seem to work with Google Chrome. I tried it with Firefox and it worked great. Screenshots:

**Chrome**

http://oi58.tinypic.com/148jjw5.jpg

**Firefox**

http://oi58.tinypic.com/5fiy41.jpg

The HTML and CSS I'm using:

```
<style>
.form-inline .form-group {
    margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 4px;
}
.form-inline > .form-group {
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
<form id="callForm" action="sendCall.php"  method="post"  class="form-inline" >

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="your">Your phone number</label>
<span class="input-group-addon">+91</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your" name="your" placeholder="Your 10 digit number" required />
</div>
</div>


 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
 <div class="input-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="frnd">Friend's number</label>
<span class="input-group-addon">+</span>
    <input text="text" class="form-control" id="frnd" name="frnd" placeholder="Your friend's number" required />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Connet</button>
</div>
</form>
<script>
```

Comment: Your markup and css display correctly in Chrome
may be some other css rules overridden your page's css rulls

Comment: @Hossein Salmanian  so why does it look ok in firefox?

Comment: @Ashish Please check your other css, something is overridding the current css

Comment: @Gorostas Okay i understand that but if it is so then why does it look right in Firefox?

Comment: Did you work this out? I have a feeling it's to do with normalize.css not setting a default for a property, so the Chrome UA CSS is overriding and cocking the whole thing up. If you work out which property it is, please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your `sr-only` element *inside* the `input-group`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label class="sr-only" for="your">Your phone number</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">+91</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="your" name="your" placeholder="Your 10 digit number" required />
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, if this fix an extra border (and maybe a floating issue), I doubt this is the only thing to change.
You may have another CSS rule which broke your layout.

Answer (score 0):

For me its working fine on both browser, may be your CSS is not working properly or you are using the old version CSS. 
check your css or may be some other properties are overwriting your css that could be the problm.
their is no problem in this code.

```
<form class="form-inline" >
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
 <div class="input-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="frnd">Friend's number</label>
<span class="input-group-addon">+</span>
    <input text="text" class="form-control" id="frnd" name="frnd" placeholder="Your friend's number" required />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Connet</button>
</div>
</form>
```